# Compare rows and replace values in one of the rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| Year | Quarter | Year-Month | Current Value | Future Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Q3 | 2021-10 | 0.411 | NaN | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021 | Q4 | 2022-01 | -0.100 | NaN | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022 | Q1 | 2022-04 | -0.224 | NaN | 2022-04-01 |
| 2022 | Q1 | 2022-03 | 0.110 | 0.092 | 2022-03-01 |

In the last two rows it can be seen that the Year and Quarter values are duplicates but the Year-Month, no. So, what I want to do in this case is to identify such cases. In this example where Year and Quarter are duplicates, I want to take the value from the last one, move it to the row above and delete the last row. So the result will look like this:

| Year | Quarter | Year-Month | Current Value | Future Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | Q3 | 2021-10 | 0.411 | NaN | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021 | Q4 | 2022-01 | -0.100 | NaN | 2022-01-01 |
| 2022 | Q1 | 2022-04 | -0.224 | 0.092 | 2022-04-01 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming rows are sorted by decreasing Year-Month, you can use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) with a crafted dictionary for aggregation ('first' value by default, 'last' for "Future Value"):

```
d = {c: 'first' for c in df}
d['Future Value'] = 'last'

out = df.groupby(['Year', 'Quarter'], as_index=False).agg(d)
```

output:

```
   Year Quarter Year-Month  Current Value  Future Value        Date
0  2021      Q3    2021-10          0.411           NaN  2021-10-01
1  2021      Q4    2022-01         -0.100           NaN  2022-01-01
2  2022      Q1    2022-04         -0.224         0.092  2022-04-01
```

Comment: Seems this is working for me, although I haven't used agg function and I have to understand what is happening. Thanks for the solution.